# Calculation of time and space complexity

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, time-complexity, space-complexity

I am working on this Leetcode problem - "Given a string containing digits from 2-9 inclusive, return all possible letter combinations that the number could represent. Return the answer in any order.

A mapping of digit to letters (just like on the telephone buttons) is given below.
Note that 1  does not map to any letters."

[image]

This is a recursive solution to the problem that I was able to understand, but I am not able to figure out the time and space complexity of the solution.

```
if not len(digits):
        return []
    
    res = []
    
    my_dict = {
        '2':'abc',
        '3':'def',
        '4':'ghi',
        '5':'jkl',
        '6':'mno',
        '7':'pqrs',
        '8':'tuv',
        '9':'wxyz'
    }
    
    if len(digits) == 1:
        return list(my_dict[digits[0]])
    
    my_list = my_dict[digits[0]] #string - abc
    
    for i in range(len(my_list)): # i = 0,1,2
        for item in self.letterCombinations(digits[1:]):
            print(item)
            res.append(my_list[i] + item) 
    return res
```

Any help or explanation regarding calculating time and space complexity for this solution would be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With certain combinatorial problems, the time and space complexity can become dominated by the size of the output. Looking at the loops and function calls, the work being done in the function is one string concatenation and one append for each element of the output. There's also up to 4 repeated recursive calls to `self.letterCombinations(digits[1:])`: assuming these aren't cached, we need to add in the extra repeated work being done there.

We can write a formula for the number of operations needed to solve the problem when `len(digits) == n`. If T(n) is the number of steps, and A(n) is the length of the answer array, we get `T(n) = 4*T(n-1) + n*A(n) + O(1)`. We get an extra multiplicative factor of n on A(n) because string concatenation is linear time; an implementation with lists and `str.join()` would avoid that.

Since A(n) is upper-bounded by 4^n, and T(1) is a constant, this gives `T(n) = O(n * (4^n))`; the space complexity here is also `O(n * (4^n))`, given 4^n strings of length n.

One possibly confusing part of complexity analysis is that it's usually a worst-case analysis unless specified otherwise. That's why we use 4 instead of 3 here: if any input could give 4^n results, we use that figure, even though many digit inputs would give closer to 3^n results.